# Flutter get lat and long value where marker pointer is

Tags: flutter, dart

I am showing google Maps and simple markers at the center of the map. What I need to do is I need to print the updated long and lat value where the marker is. I need to print the value only.

My code

```
class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  LatLng currentPostion;
  bool showMap = false;
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> _markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  int _markerIdCounter = 0;
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getUserLocation();
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    _mapController.complete(controller);
    if (currentPostion != null) {
      MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(_markerIdVal());
      LatLng position = currentPostion;
      Marker marker = Marker(
        markerId: markerId,
        position: position,
        draggable: false,
      );
      setState(() {
        _markers[markerId] = marker;
      });

      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
        GoogleMapController controller = await _mapController.future;
        controller.animateCamera(
          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
            CameraPosition(
              target: position,
              zoom: 17.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  }

  String _markerIdVal({bool increment = false}) {
    String val = 'marker_id_$_markerIdCounter';
    if (increment) _markerIdCounter++;
    print(val);
    return val;
  }

  void _getUserLocation() async {
    var position = await GeolocatorPlatform.instance
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    setState(() {
      currentPostion = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

      showMap = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Select Location',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ).tr(),
      ),
      body: showMap
          ? Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: GoogleMap(
                markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers.values),
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: currentPostion,
                  zoom: 18.0,
                ),
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {
                  if (_markers.length > 0) {
                    MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(_markerIdVal());
                    Marker marker = _markers[markerId];
                    Marker updatedMarker = marker.copyWith(
                      positionParam: position.target,
                    );

                    setState(() {
                      _markers[markerId] = updatedMarker;
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
          : Center(
              child: SpinKitWave(
                  color: kPrimaryColor, type: SpinKitWaveType.center)),
    );
  }
}
```

I just need to print the updated long and lat where the marker is. It's working correctly marker is changing its position but doesn't give value or I don't know how can I do it. I don't want to use draggable pointer option so that's why try this way.

Comment: Do you want to print the values when `onCameraMove` is called? If so, `position.target` is of type `LatLng`, so you can access the `latitude` and `longitude` properties on it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said you already can change the position of the marker, which means that `updatedMarker` is working as expected. You can get the latitude and longitude of the updated marker by

```dart
int updatedLat = updatedMarker.position.latitude;
int updatedLong = updatedMarker.position.longitude;
```

You can perhaps store the updated latitude and longitude values inside the `setState()` where you assign `updatedMarker` to the array.

You can go through the documentation of the plugin to know more about it.

https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/Marker-class.html